# (Ubuntu desktop 16.10) Xrdp connecting ... Disconnect

Tags: xorg, remote-desktop, xrdp

Ubuntu desktop 16.10. `Xrdp connecting ... Disconnect`
I installed Ubuntu desktop 16.10 in vmware workstation 12.5 pro

install xrdp
vmware port forwarding
local : 3389 / remote : 3395
/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini default Config File (not modified)
(xrdp all config file default)
execute mstsc.exe (windows 10)

https://s15.postimg.org/bpi1r8j0b/Honeycam_2017-04-15_21-50-38.gif

What's the problem?

`xrdp.ini` file:

```
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true
; tcp port to listen
port=3389
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate
; minimum security level allowed for client
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=
; specify whether SSLv3 should be disabled
#disableSSLv3=true
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=60

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/var/run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

[console]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[vnc-any]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[sesman-any]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[rdp-any]
name=rdp-any
lib=librdp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389

[neutrinordp-any]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In my case, all I got was a blank screen after login. I found that the Xvnc session works but the Xorg session does not (options provided by the login screen)

I had to comment out the Xorg option in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` so it would default to Xvnc.

To do this, edit the file with root permission (eg `sudo nano /etc/xrdp.ini`), find the section:

```
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20
```

and put semicolons at the start of each line:

```
;[Xorg]
;name=Xorg
;lib=libxup.so
;username=ask
;password=ask
;ip=127.0.0.1
;port=-1
;code=20
```

save the file and exit.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but could you be more specific on ''commenting out' the Xorg option?  I saw a Xorg section, no option.  Ideally, you could add the exact modification in your answer to help better.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem connecting with Remmina and the solution for me was to provide credentials on Remmina prior to connect.